# How detect location.hostname in child window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need in javascript (or JQuery) detect the actual url from the child window tab..

Example:

**parent.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function openInNewTab(url) {
        var child = window.open(url, '_blank');
        child.focus();
        var timer = setInterval(checkChild, 500);

        function checkChild() {

            document.write("Show here the location.hostname from child window");

        }

    }

</script>

<button onclick="openInNewTab('//mypage.com/child.php');">Open Child</button>
```

**child.php**

```
<a href="//google.com">Go to google</a>
<a href="//facebook.com">Go to facebook</a>
```

if user open child.php, show in parent.php "mypage.com" but if the user press click in the "**go to google**" show in parent.php "**google.com**" or in "**go to facebook**" show "**facebook.com**"

I need work this in javascript (or JQuery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function openInNewTab(url) {
    var child = window.open(url, '_blank');
    child.focus();
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        checkChild(child);      
    }, 500);

    function checkChild(child) {
        document.write(child.location.href , "   ");
    }

}
```

Comment: @diana_sweden Great, please accept the Answer and upvote if it worked for you.